# Is the frame of a method at same point has same type in all time?

Tags: java

I've recently been looking at [The Java Virtual Machine Specifications (JVMS)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html). and [ASM of A Java bytecode engineering library](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf) to try to better understand JVM, but I've found something about A stack map frame that I'm not quite getting...

I understand that A stack map frame gives the state of the execution frame of a method at some point during its execution. But I don't understand the stack map frame of any instructions is the same type and  the same size when it is executed from any jump instructions.

Anyway, I have two specific questions:

1. Is the frame of a method at same point has the same type and the same size in all time?
2. If yes, how the java compiler or jvm do that?